# Jquery script not working on my computer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with a script on this website I try to build. This is the script itself:

```
var id=0;
var cases=$('.cases').length;
$('#show').html($('#'+id).html());
setInterval(function() 
{
    $('#show').empty();
    if (id==cases-1)
        id=0;
    else
        id++;
    $('#show').html($('#'+id).html());
},5000);
```

this is the html code:

```
<div class="page">
    <br /><br /><headline>cases</headline><br /><br /><div id='case'></div><div class='content'><div id='show'></div><div id='column1'><div class='cases' id='0'><div class='short'><div id='cases-image'><img src='images/Sunset.jpg'/></div><div id='cases-info'><div id='cases-headline'>zxfbzsxdbfsdfh</div><cases-text>dfghsdfgsdfgsdfg</cases-text><div class='more' id=zxfbzsxdbfsdfh >להמשך קריאה...</div></div></div></div></div><div id='column2'><div class='cases' id='1'><div class='short'><div id='cases-image'><img src='images/גלריה1.bmp'/></div><div id='cases-info'><div id='cases-headline'>xbzsdfbsdf</div><cases-text>dafasdvasdvasdv</cases-text><div class='more' id=xbzsdfbsdf >להמשך קריאה...</div></div></div></div></div>            </div>
        <div id="footer">
</div>
```

It works in jsFiddle, but it doesn't work on my computer, it only shows the first case, the id in the script changes, but it doesn't get the html from the other cases... Can you help me?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/nzUb6/

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var id=0;
    var cases=$('.cases').length;
    $('#show').html($('#'+id).html());
    setInterval(function() 
    {
        $('#show').empty();
        if (id==cases-1)
            id=0;
        else
            id++;
        $('#show').html($('#'+id).html());
    },5000);

});
</script>
```

if your code worked in fiddle then it should work on your computer for sure if follow the conventions.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem, I'm using the latest version of jquery. thanks anyway

Comment: i mean the latest version of jquery on your local system

Answer (score 0):

make sure

you have included the jQuery.js

you have wrapped the code inside the ready handler like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 //your code
});
</script>
```

Comment: I did those things, that's not the problem